# How to open website url from windows application(.net) (no javascript)

Tags: asp.net, windows

I want to open website url(in default browser) from my windows application.
it is successfully open using below code :

"`Process.Start(URL);`"

Now my problem is:

i do not want to show the url of the website due to security reason.
**So how can i hide addressbar of popup browser**.

Thanks.

Comment: If for real you do have some security data on the url - then they are not secure, and even if your user can not see them, the middle proxy can. We do not place sensitive, unencrypted data on the url.

Comment: @ Aristos ya that is okay.. but i want to do like at the first time users should not able to see the url.

Comment: As far as I know most modern browser won't let you hide the address bar for security reasons. Most browsers highlight SSL errors using the address bar for example.

Comment: it can possible using javascript using `window.open()` but i don't know **How to write javascript in asp.net windows application**

Comment: webBrowser1.Document.Window.Open(new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com/"), "displayWindow", "status=yes,width=200,height=400", false);

Comment: The only way is to use a frame or iframe inside the window, and this can do the job for non experienced users. Maybe is something else that you wan do ?

Comment: @Shafqat Masood - I want to open in browser not in webBrowser control.

Comment: see my answer i have tried that and it is working, it will open a browser window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dear please add webbrowser control in your solution make it invisible and assign anyurl to that document like

```
       this.webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("http://www.google.com", System.UriKind.Absolute);
```

and then on button click u can open webbrowser

```
      webBrowser1.Document.Window.Open(new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com"), "displayWindow", "status=yes,width=200,height=400", false);
```

screenshot is [image]

using the process.run method use this

create one html file paste that in side the folder where the exe is with the following code

```
 <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title></title>
   <script>
      window.open('', '_self', '');
      window.open('http://www.microsoft.com', '', 'status=yes,width=200,height=400', false);
      window.close();
    </script>
   </head>
 <body>

 </body>
 </html>
```

and in ur button click code write as

```
  Process.Start(Application.StartupPath+ @"\HTMLPage1.html");
```

Comment: Thanks. it's working, it's open in internet Explorer browser but i want to open it in default browser of the PC.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shafqat.... can you pls help, this should open in default browser of the PC.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.Diagonists.process.start("http//:www.google")
```